# Template not being displayed on click on Vue link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm creating a Laravel website that will be a single page application. I'm new to VueJS even if I have experience with javascript in general.

I need to display several routes, such as `/blog/new`, `/blog/:id`, `/blog/edit`, etc. `/blog` itself is defined by Laravel, and works as the blog index.

I installed `vue-router`, and tried to follow some examples I saw but nothing happens:

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const blogIndex = { template: require('./components/blog/index.vue') };
const blogNew = { template: require('./components/blog/new.vue')};

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/blog',
        component: blogIndex,
        name: 'blog-index'
    },

    {
        path: '/blog/new',
        component: blogNew,
        name: 'blog-new'
    }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: "history"
});

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));
Vue.component('navbar', require('./components/Navbar.vue'));
Vue.component('blog_index', require('./components/blog/index.vue'));
console.log(testvar);

const app = new Vue({
    router
}).$mount('#app');
```

**components/blog/index.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Blog index</h1>
        <router-link :to="{ name: 'blog-new' }">New article</router-link>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
   export default {
       mounted() {
           console.log('blog#index mounted');
       }
   }
</script>
```

**components/blog/new.vue**

```
<template>
    <h2>Here is blog/new y'all</h2>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('blog#new mounted');
        }
    }
</script>
```

So far, the only thing that works is my address bar that gets modified, but the template itself doesn't seem to be loaded (I go from `/blog` to `/blog/new`).

I've seen that I need add `<router-view></router-view>` in my html file, but this triggers an error and blocks VueJS's display.

My question is: what am I missing, or what did I do wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<router-view></router-view>` in your main `App.vue` file, which is the part that new routes are loaded into.

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

You currently state you have this in components/blog/index.vue - which I believe is just for your nested routes. https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html

Comment: You were right, I didn't put `<router-view></router-view>` in the right place, thanks!